# w3schools is down and i need access to the w3.css file

Tags: php, html, w3.css

I am currently using w3.css to make my website responsive, and since w3schools is down my whole website is now in pieces. I was wondering if there's anywhere else I can grab the w3.css file.

I am linking the server version of the w3.css file and this seems to be the problem

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">`

Comment: https://www.quanzhanketang.com/w3css/w3css_downloads.html

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I had the same problem, I fixed it by downloading the CSS file (w3.css) from github.

The site of W3Schools was down for a few hours, but they fixed it, your page should be fine right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply download and upload in your root css directory and include instead of using cdn.

Save css from below url

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css